# Youtube API loads video but doesn't play

Tags: android-youtube-api

I have integrated my Youtube API into my app, and have created two youTubePlayerView instances. The first loads fine and allows to be selected, the second is inside of a firebase statement and won't allow me to select it. However the video loads fine into the youtube api for the second video. But it just won't play the video when selected.

code for the first video:

```
 youTubePlayerView.initialize(Constants.youTubeKey,
                                        new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                                                YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                                                // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.
                                                youTubePlayer.cueVideo("YbjRc2dflZU");
                                            }
                                            @Override
                                            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                                                YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                                            }
                                        });
```

code for the second video:

```
final DatabaseReference artistsFound = Constants.artistRef
                .child(userSelectedStage)
                .child(userSelectedDate)
                .child(userSelectedArtist);
        artistsFound.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String valueFound = snapshot.getKey().toString();
                        if(valueFound.equals("Set Time")){
                            String artistSetTime = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            txtVwDetArtistSetTime.setText(artistSetTime);
                        }else if(valueFound.equals("Featured Video")){
                            final String artistFeaturedVideoURL = snapshot.getValue().toString();

                            youTubePlayerViewFeature.initialize(Constants.youTubeKey,
                                    new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                                            YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                                            // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.
                                            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(artistFeaturedVideoURL);
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                                                            YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
```